# JPA not usable with CDI scopes that are managed in HttpSession?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, cdi, entitymanager, serializable

All CDI managed beans that belong to a scope that is ultimately bound to the HttpSession need to be serializable. Which means all attributes need to be serializable. EntityManager is not though this seems to be considered a bug ([here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/openjpa-dev/200702.mbox/%3C7D856CDFE035FF45A0420ACBD71BDD63032E61D8@repbex02.amer.bea.com%3E) and [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/EJBTHREE-10?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel) (I don't know why it's closed.)).

This means if you want to adhere to the spec you cannot use JPA from CDI scopes like Session or Conversation.

Seems Java EE is close to unusable or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're right : `EntityManager` is not serializable, but do you think CDI EG didn't notice that :-) ?

So when a CDI bean is Serialized (i.e. passivation of a SFSB) the EntityManager is considered as transient and is not. When then bean is unserialized the EntityManager is automatically re-injected in the Bean and so it works as it used to be.

The problem is when you use Extended Persistence Context in your Bean. Java EE spec doesn't support serialization of such bean. But framework like Seam 2 for Java EE 5 or CDI extension like Seam3 Persistence in Java EE 6 gives you possibilities to manage those special use cases.

Comment: thanks for information. I've taken a look at the EJB 3.1 spec and it states that: 'A container must not passivate a stateful session bean with an extended persistence context unless the following conditions are met: 1. All the entities in the persistence context are serializable. 2. The EntityManager is serializable. The container is not permitted to destroy a stateful session bean instance because it does not meet these requirements.'

If I understand it correctly, the SFSB that cannot be passivated must remain in the memory. How does it look in the case of a Session Scoped CDI bean?

Comment: @Antoine, thanks for the info but you you elaborate how exactly Seam 3 is able to handle serialization of an Extended Persistence Context or point me to some resources?

Comment: I didn't test this mechanism in Seam 3, but in Seam 2 it used to work you can check some documentation here : http://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest/reference/en-US/html/ClusteringAndEJBPassivation.html
Seam 2 pojo have the same facility.

I'll check if it has been ported to Seam 3 persistence for EJB and Simple CDI bean and will keep you posted.

Comment: That ONLY works with proprietary features e.g. of Hibernate. With CDI only a proxy is injected and the proxy is serializable, if you don't use a dependent scoped Entity-Manager. The Entity-Manager has to be in the Request-Scope or you will get problems as soon as the session gets serialized e.g. in case of session replication and without proprietary features. I think i saw this hint in the documentation of the JPA Module of MyFaces CODI.

Comment: It doesn't even work with 'proprietary features' in Hibernate. It will in some cases just loose state without telling you the truth :/

Atm you can only use the entitymanager-per-request pattern. And even here you need to add magic properties in persistence.xml to have the entities Serializable (and don't loose the info about their _loaded and _dirty flags).

As Dar Whi pointed out: in CDI you should use a producer method for creating a RequestScoped EntityManager.